# RapidMiner: How can I efficiently generate n-grams?

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

For my thesis, I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis on larger (up to 2GB) files of text documents (product reviews) using RapidMiner Community Edition with the Text Mining extension.

I'd like to generate bigrams for that. But for a small 70MB csv file with not even 100.000 documents the generation of bigrams already takes 12 hours on an eight-core 32GB RAM machine (with RapidMiner configured to use 28GB and all cores).

I've been able to reduce it to 3 hours using filters with the downside of having bigrams, which do not exist in the original documents. I'm not sure, if this is as far as I can get.

My current process looks like this:

`Read CSV` -> `Process documents` (`Tokenize` -> `Stem` -> `Filter stop words` -> `Filter length < 2` -> `Generate n-grams` ) -> `Split Validation`

Removing the n-gram operator drops precision and recall down to ~60%, which is far from being acceptable. Thanks for any ideas, how to speed this up.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, using the operator `Materialize Data` can make a difference. Put this after the processing of the documents and immediately before the splitting operator.

You could also look at pruning to reduce the number of attributes. You would have to find the optimum parameters through experiment.

Another option is to implement a word list as input to the `Process Documents` operator. This, of course, needs a known list of words which may not be an appropriate approach for your problem.

It is also possible to filter by content when processing documents. You could include only those tokens that contain an underscore. This will keep 2-grams and above and delete unigrams and consequently will reduce the number of attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not the validation step. The problem is with the `generate n-gram` operator, which takes a long time to process. I'm already trying to reduce the number of tokens as much as possible with filter operators. Maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: The pruning, word list and filtering suggestions above are all part of the `Process Documents` operator and may help with the n-gram generation.